# Can't add Search button to Action Bar in Android Developer Tutorial

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I am trying to add the Search button to the Android Action bar by following this tutorial:
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/adding-buttons.html

I modified by minSdkVersion to 11 in my Manifest.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

I have added the action_search item in a `main.xml` file located in the `menu` folder:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:showAsAction="never"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

Eclipse has provided the method already for the menu, which I have not changed:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

I've added the string to my `strings.xml`: `<string name="action_search">Search</string>` and included `ic_action_search.png` in my drawable folders.

There are no errors upon launch. I see the Settings menu item in the overflow. But I do not see the search button anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove this value: `collapseActionView`

Replace this line:

```
android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
```

with for example this

```
android:showAsAction="never"
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! Could you explain what collapseActionView does?