# problems with adding action button in android tutorial

Tags: java, android

I am following the android tutorial and i have problems with adding the search button to the action bar.

I have the following main_activity_actions.xml because i support android version 8:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <!-- Search, should appear as action button -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
    <!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
          android:title="@string/action_settings"
          yourapp:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Then in the MainActivity class:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu items for use in the action bar
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_activity_actions, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle presses on the action bar items
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_search:
            //  openSearch();
                return true;
            case R.id.action_settings:
            //  openSettings();
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
}
```

This is my style.xml which should be ok:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

</resources>
```

this is my screen I don't see the search action button [image: screen]

.

What else could i check?
I cannot find anything additional in the web.
The following answers of stackoverflow did not help me:
[Can't add Search button to Action Bar in Android Developer Tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19096285/cant-add-search-button-to-action-bar-in-android-developer-tutorial?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the following error:
The styles.xml at v14 looked the following

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

The search button was not visible because the action bar was black and the search icon was not visible .

When changing to

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

it becomes visible.